# Shortest Hamilton Path Planar Problem

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

I think that the problem to obtain the shortest path visiting once time each point (it is not needed to come back to start point so it is a Hamilton path), in its planar euclidean and symmetric version is an NP-complete problem.

Wikipedia says:

"If the distance measure is a metric and symmetric, the problem becomes APX-complete"

I´m not sure if wikipedia is correct, please can anyone clarify if this problem is NP-complete, APX-complete or both? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say "I'm not sure of that, please can ..." What does "that" refer to?  The entire sentence (both of the complexity measures)?  Can you phrase your question precisely?

Comment: Thx Burr, take a look now if it is more precise

Comment: Hmm, Wikipedia's reference for the claim seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

Cristos H. Papadimitriou says that "[The Euclidean Travelling Salesman Problem Is NP-Complete](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397577900123)" He based its demonstration reducing the Exact Cover Problem to it, wich is known NP-complete. In general the ETSP is NP-hard when the inputs are real coordenates, but restricting the input to integers such as the distances can be P computables, it is NP-complete. This is explained in page 239: "In what follows we will assume that the elements of the distance matrix are the integral parts of this metric. Any desired precision can be thus obtained by increasing the scale accordingly. Moreover in the constructions that will follow we will also allow rational coordinates, with the understanding that the scale will be eventually multiplied by an adequately large integer, so that all coordinates become integral and any necessary precision is obtained."

Ola Svensson in "[Approximation Algorithms and Hardness of Approximation](http://theory.epfl.ch/osven/courses/Approx13/Notes/lecture4-5.pdf)" is using a similar restriction to the inputs to obtain a PTAS with the Sanjeev Arora´s method wich has a  $(1 + 1/c)-approximation$ where $c$ is the number of dimensions of the coordinates inputs; 3/2-aproximation for the planar problem is not good enough aproach.

So, the Shortest Hamilton Path Planar Problem, even restrincting inputs to a P computable distances is NP-complete, and APX-complete too.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is polynomially equivalent to the (minimum) Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP). It cannot be [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) since it is not a decision problem, but it is surely [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness), because the Hamiltonian Cycle Problem is a particular case of TSP and is NP-complete.

$\Delta$TSP problem is TSP with metrics (triangle inequality). It is [known to be APX-hard](https://hal-univ-paris13.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00003997/document) (the referred article is [here](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/moor.18.1.1?journalCode=moor), however authors don't operate terms of APX, since this class was introduced later). More precisely it is polynomially $\frac32$-approximable, but is NP-hard to be $(1+\varepsilon)$-approximated for small enough positive $\varepsilon$. Also $\Delta$TSP belongs to APX, so it is APX-complete.

So your problem is NP-hard and APX-complete, too. (By the way the first statement follows from the last one.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Smylic, very well clarified.

Comment: Cristos H. Papadimitriou says that "The Euclidean Travelling Salesman Problem Is NP-Complete" http://ac.els-cdn.com/0304397577900123/1-s2.0-0304397577900123-main.pdf?_tid=c959d962-8780-11e7-842f-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1503437466_141a81b03c0f27cd7eb8255b8724e4d2 I think that he referes to the problem when the distances are P computables. Don´t you?

Comment: Ixer, read the first paragraph: “The Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP) can be stated as follows: Given $(n - 1)n/2$ integers denoting the distances between all pairs of $n$ cities...”. This means that any distance can be got in a constant time. (Concerning terminology, NP-hardness and NP-completeness where separated a bit later than this article was published.)

Comment: So it is NP-hard even when distances are given in integer, hence the decision problem (try if a path is the shortest) must be NP-complete? Ummm ... I think it can be verified in polinomial time.

Comment: The decision version of TSP can be stated as follows: given graph with distances and value $\ell$, check whether graph has a cycle of weight at most $\ell$. You version doesn't belong to NP.

Comment: Excuse me if I misunderstanding the concept. My decision version of eTSP would be: given a matrix of integers representing distances between each point $p$ and a hamilton path $HP$ defined by a secuence of points ${p_1, p_1, ..., p_n}$, check if $HP$ is the shortest hamilton path. Note that there are 2^(n-1) $HPs$.

Comment: There are $(n - 2)!$ Hamiltonian paths with given ends $p_1$ and $p_n$. Anyway problem to check whether given path is the shortest one doesn't belong to class NP, because each problem in NP could be solved in polynomial time with an additional polynomial amount of information called *certificate*. Non-existence of certificate indicates that problem has no solution. In your case there is no such certificate, therefore problem is not in NP. In my case there is such certificate, it is a path of length at most $\ell$. Read definitions please.

Comment: In my case the certificate is the Hamilton Path as a secuence of points, to verify if there is one other smaller in a complete Graph. If it runs in polinomical The Euclidean Travelling Salesman Problem Is NP-Complete, isn´t it?

Comment: No, given a graph and a path you cannot check in polynomial time that there is no shorter path in this graph. Therefore path is not a certeficate of being the shortest one.

Comment: Take a look to the Lemma 2 in Papadimitriou´s paper. It is a certification to the Exact Cover Problem, to wich is reduced my problem.